# Placeholder not changing value in form

Tags: javascript

I have a form. This form has input fields which have placeholders. These placeholders should adjust their value depending on the value of a variable (languageFirstTwo).

I'm baffeled, as one placeholder inside the input field changes the value while the other one doens't (first name changes, email does not).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
var language = navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language;
languageFirstTwo = language.substr(0,2); //doesn't have var/let/const for a reason

lngs = document.getElementsByClassName("lng");


let fname = document.getElementById("fname"); 
let email = document.getElementById("email"); 

placeholders = {
 sl: { fname: "Janez", email: "moj@email.si" },
 en: { fname: "John", email: "my@email.us" }, 
 de: { fname: "Kommissar", email: "mein@email.deu" },
 it: { fname: "Fabio", email: "barilla@email.it"},
 hr: { fname: "Mirko", email: "moj@email.hr"},
 ru: { fname: "Mikayl", email: "moji@email.ru"}
}; 

init2(languageFirstTwo);

function init2(languageFirstTwo) {
 if (Object.keys(placeholders).includes(languageFirstTwo)){
  const values = placeholders[languageFirstTwo];
   fname.setAttribute("placeholder", values.fname); //changes
   email.setAttribute("placeholder", values.email); //does not change
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z][^0-9]{2,25}" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="John" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"/>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="45" placeholder="my@email.com"/>
</form>
```

Comment: your code seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you provided works fine when tested. See JS fiddle demo below- 
[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x9vhw65j/2/)

Can you please double check the below-

- There is no other tag with `id ="email"` except in your form.
- `languageFirstTwo` value matches the key in `placeholders`

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the effort, but the issue has already been found. Waithing the necessary amount of time to close the question.